# Bison: When I try to add action in function grammar rule, the segmentation fault 11 occur

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison

I have a problem about segmentation fault 11.

Every time, when I want to add action rules in function grammar blocks, I must get the segmentation fault 11.

Therefore, I cannot get the dump.out, which is a file that record the identifiers for me.

I do not think the problem is because of the scanner file, but that is still possible.

Of course, the problem should have something about symbol table, but it is really strange.

The problem just occurs like:

**function: FN ID '(' ')' {if ($2->st_type == UNDEF) $2->st_type = FUNCTION_TYPE};**

When I add action in the block, segmentation fault 11 will occur.

However, this is okay.
**function: FN ID '(' ')' {};**

**The parser file do not contains all contents since it is so many.**

**I use mac os**

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you anyway

---

Where the error occur

```
1: // Hello World Example
<fn>
<id: main>
<(>
<)>
<{>
2: fn main() {
3:   // Print text to the console
<let>
<mut>
<id: a>
<:>
<int>
<=>
<integer: 10>
<;>
4:   let mut a:int = 10;
<let>
<mut>
<id: b>
<=>
<string: 1199>
<;>
5:   let mut b = "1199";
<let>
<mut>
<id: sum>
<[>
<str>
<,>
<integer: 10>
<]>
<;>
6:   let mut sum[str, 10];
<id: sum>
<[>
<integer: 0>
<]>
<=>
<string: 100>
<;>
7:   sum[0] = "100";
<id: b>
<=>
<string: 123>
<+>
<id: b>
<;>
8:   b = "123" + b;
<println>
<(>
<string: Hello World>
<)>
<;>
9:   println ("Hello World");
<}>
10: }

Symbol table:
a
b
sum
main
Segmentation fault: 11
```

---

The input file

```
// Hello World Example
fn main() {
  // Print text to the console
  let mut a:int = 10;
  let mut b = "1199";
  let mut sum[str, 10];
  sum[0] = "100";
  b = "123" + b;
  println ("Hello World");
}
```

---

This is my symbol table header file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* maximum size of hash table */
#define SIZE 211

/* maximum size of tokens-identifiers */
#define MAXTOKENLEN 40

/* token types */
#define UNDEF 0
#define INT_TYPE 1
#define REAL_TYPE 2
#define STR_TYPE 3
#define LOGIC_TYPE 4
#define ARRAY_TYPE 5
#define FUNCTION_TYPE 6
/* new type for parser */
#define CONST_INT_TYPE 7
#define CONST_REAL_TYPE 8
#define CONST_STR_TYPE 9
#define CONST_LOGIC_TYPE 10

/* how parameter is passed */
#define BY_VALUE 1
#define BY_REFER 2

/*
* Originally here, now it is in the symbols.c
* current scope
* int cur_scope = 0;
*/

/* parameter struct */
typedef struct Parameter{
    int par_type;
    char *param_name;
    // to store value
    int ival; double fval; char *st_sval; int bval; // boolean type
    int passing; // value or reference
    struct Parameter *next; // link to next one
}Param;

/* a linked list of references (lineno's) for each variable */
typedef struct Ref{ 
    int lineno;
    struct Ref *next;
    int type;
}RefList;

// struct that represents a list node
typedef struct list{
    char st_name[MAXTOKENLEN];
    int st_size;
    int scope;
    RefList *lines;
    // to store value and sometimes more information
    int st_ival; double st_fval; char *st_sval; int st_bval;
    // type
    int st_type;
    int inf_type; // for arrays (info type) and functions (return type)
    // array stuff
    int *i_vals; double *f_vals; char **s_vals; int *b_vals; // boolean type
    int array_size;
    // function parameters
    Param *parameters;
    int num_of_pars; // Meanwhile, it record the current position of the parameters
    // pointer to next item in the list
    struct list *next;
}list_t;

/* the hash table */
static list_t **hash_table;

// Function Declarations
void create(); // initialize hash table
unsigned int hash(char *key); // hash function for insert
void insert(char *name, int len, int type, int lineno); // insert entry
list_t *lookup(char *name); // search for entry
list_t *lookup_scope(char *name, int scope); // search for entry in scope
void hide_scope(); // hide the current scope
void incr_scope(); // go to next scope
void dump(FILE *of); // dump file
```

---

This is symbol table code file.

```
#include "symbols.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* current scope */
int cur_scope = 0;

void create()
{
    int i; 
    hash_table = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(list_t*));
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) hash_table[i] = NULL;
}

unsigned int hash(char *key)
{
    unsigned int hashval = 0;
    for(;*key!='\0';key++) hashval += *key;
    hashval += key[0] % 11 + (key[0] << 3) - key[0];
    return hashval % SIZE;
}

void insert(char *name, int len, int type, int lineno)
{
    unsigned int hashval = hash(name); // hash function used
    list_t *l = hash_table[hashval];

    while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0)) l = l->next;

    /* variable not yet in table */
    if (l == NULL){
        l = (list_t*) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        strncpy(l->st_name, name, len);  
        /* add to hashtable */
        l->st_type = type;
        l->scope = cur_scope;
        l->lines = (RefList*) malloc(sizeof(RefList));
        l->lines->lineno = lineno;
        l->lines->next = NULL;
        l->next = hash_table[hashval];
        hash_table[hashval] = l; 
        // printf("Inserted %s for the first time with linenumber %d!\n", name, lineno); // error checking
    }
    /* found in table, so just add line number */
    else{
        l->scope = cur_scope;
        RefList *t = l->lines;
        while (t->next != NULL) t = t->next;
        /* add linenumber to reference list */
        t->next = (RefList*) malloc(sizeof(RefList));
        t->next->lineno = lineno;
        t->next->next = NULL;
        // printf("Found %s again at line %d!\n", name, lineno);
    }
}

list_t *lookup(char *name)
{ /* return symbol if found or NULL if not found */
    unsigned int hashval = hash(name);
    list_t *l = hash_table[hashval];
    while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0)) l = l->next;
    return l; // NULL is not found
}

list_t *lookup_scope(char *name, int scope)
{ /* return symbol if found or NULL if not found */
    unsigned int hashval = hash(name);
    list_t *l = hash_table[hashval];
    while ((l != NULL) && (strcmp(name,l->st_name) != 0) && (scope != l->scope)) l = l->next;
    return l; // NULL is not found
}

void hide_scope()
{ /* hide the current scope */
    if(cur_scope > 0) cur_scope--;
}
void incr_scope()
{ /* go to next scope */
    cur_scope++;
}

/* print to stdout by default */ 
void dump(FILE * of)
{  
  int i; int count; // record whether first line prints or not.

  fprintf(of,"------------ ----------------- -------------\n");
  fprintf(of,"Name         Type              Line Numbers\n");
  fprintf(of,"------------ ----------------- -------------\n");

  for (i=0; i < SIZE; ++i){ 
    if (hash_table[i] != NULL){ 
        list_t *l = hash_table[i];
        while (l != NULL){ 
            RefList *t = l->lines;
            fprintf(of,"%-12s ",l->st_name);

            printf("%s\n", l->st_name); // print out all the names in the symbol table

            if (l->st_type == INT_TYPE) fprintf(of,"%-7s","int");
            else if (l->st_type == REAL_TYPE) fprintf(of,"%-7s","real");
            else if (l->st_type == STR_TYPE) fprintf(of,"%-7s","string");
            else if (l->st_type == LOGIC_TYPE)  fprintf(of,"%-7s","bool");
            else if (l->st_type == CONST_INT_TYPE) fprintf(of, "%-7s", "const_int"); // constant_int_type
            else if (l->st_type == CONST_REAL_TYPE) fprintf(of, "%-7s", "const_real"); // constant_real_type
            else if (l->st_type == CONST_STR_TYPE) fprintf(of, "%-7s", "const_string"); // constant_string_type
            else if (l->st_type == CONST_LOGIC_TYPE) fprintf(of, "%-7s", "const_bool"); // const_logic_type
            else if (l->st_type == ARRAY_TYPE){
                fprintf(of,"array of ");
                if (l->inf_type == INT_TYPE)           fprintf(of,"%-7s","int");
                else if (l->inf_type  == REAL_TYPE)    fprintf(of,"%-7s","real");
                else if (l->inf_type  == STR_TYPE)     fprintf(of,"%-7s","string");
                else if (l->inf_type == LOGIC_TYPE)    fprintf(of,"%-7s","bool");
                else fprintf(of,"%-7s","undef");
            }
            else if (l->st_type == FUNCTION_TYPE){
                fprintf(of,"%-7s %s","function returns ");
                if (l->inf_type == INT_TYPE)           fprintf(of,"%-7s","int");
                else if (l->inf_type  == REAL_TYPE)    fprintf(of,"%-7s","real");
                else if (l->inf_type  == STR_TYPE)     fprintf(of,"%-7s","string");
                else if (l->inf_type == LOGIC_TYPE)    fprintf(of,"-7%s","bool");
                else fprintf(of,"%-7s","undef");
            }
            else fprintf(of,"%-7s","undef"); // if UNDEF or 0

            count = 0;
            while (t != NULL){
                if (count == 0)
                {
                if (l->st_type == INT_TYPE || l->st_type == REAL_TYPE || l->st_type == STR_TYPE || l->st_type == UNDEF)
                    fprintf(of,"%13d ", t->lineno);
                else if (l->st_type == CONST_INT_TYPE || l->st_type == CONST_REAL_TYPE || l->st_type == CONST_STR_TYPE || l->st_type == CONST_LOGIC_TYPE)
                    fprintf(of,"%10d", t->lineno);
                else if (l->st_type == ARRAY_TYPE || l->st_type == FUNCTION_TYPE)
                    fprintf(of,"%4d", t->lineno);
                }
                else
                    fprintf(of,"%3d", t->lineno);
                count++;
                t = t->next;
            }
            fprintf(of,"\n");
            l = l->next;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

---

scanner file

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include "symbols.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"

#define LIST     strcat(buf,yytext)
#define token(t) {LIST; printf("<%s>\n");}
#define tokenInteger(t, i) {LIST; printf("<%s: %d>\n", t, i);}
#define tokenReal(t, r) {LIST; printf("<%s: %lf>\n", t, r);}
#define tokenString(t, s) {LIST; printf("<%s: %s>\n", t, s);}

#define MAX_LINE_LENG 256

extern FILE* yyin;
extern FILE* yyout;
int linenum = 1;
char buf[MAX_LINE_LENG];
char* tempStr;
int indexForStr = 1;
list_t* temp;
%}
%x Comment
%%
"//".*              {LIST;}

"/*"            {BEGIN(Comment); LIST;}
<Comment>"*/"       {LIST; BEGIN(0);}
<Comment>\n             {LIST; printf("%d: %s\n", linenum++, buf); buf[0] = '\0';}
<Comment>.      {LIST;}

"bool"      {
                token("BOOL");
                return BOOL;
                }
"break"     {token("BREAK"); return BREAK;}
"char"      {token("CHAR"); return CHAR;}
"continue"  {token("CONTINUE"); return CONTINUE;}
"do"        {token("DO"); return DO;}
"else"      {token("ELSE"); return ELSE;}
"enum"      {token("ENUM"); return ENUM;}
"extern"    {token("EXTERN"); return EXTERN;}
"false"     {token("FALSE"); yylval.boolVal = 0; return FALSE;}
"float"     {
                token("FLOAT");
                return FLOAT;
                }
"for"       {token("FOR"); return FOR;}
"fn"        {token("FN"); return FN;}
"if"        {token("IF"); return IF;}
"in"        {token("IN"); return IN;}
"int"       {
                token("INT");
                return INT;
                }
"let"       {token("LET"); return LET;}
"loop"      {token("LOOP"); return LOOP;}
"match"     {token("MATCH"); return MATCH;}
"mut"       {token("MUT"); return MUT;}
"print"     {token("PRINT"); return PRINT;}
"println"   {token("PRINTLN"); return PRINTLN;}
"pub"       {token("PUB"); return PUB;}
"return"    {token("RETURN"); return RETURN;}
"self"      {token("SELF"); return SELF;}
"static"    {token("STATIC"); return STATIC;}
"str"       {
                token("STR");
                return STR;
                }
"struct"    {token("STRUCT"); return STRUCT;}
"true"      {token("TRUE"); yylval.boolVal = 1; return TRUE;}
"use"       {token("USE"); return USE;}
"where"     {token("WHERE"); return WHERE;}
"while"     {token("WHILE"); return WHILE;}

","         {token("','"); return ',';}
":"         {token("':'"); return ':';}
";"         {token("';'"); return ';';}
"("         {token("'('"); return '(';}
")"         {token("')'"); return ')';}
"["         {token("'['"); return '[';}
"]"         {token("']'"); return ']';}
"{"         {token("'{'"); return '{';}
"}"         {token("'}'"); return '}';}

"+"         {token("'+'"); return '+';}
"-"         {token("'-'"); return '-';}
"*"         {token("'*'"); return '*';}
"/"         {token("'/'"); return '/';}
"++"        {token("'++'"); return '++';}
"--"        {token("'--'"); return '--';}
"%"     {token("'%'"); return '%';}

"<"         {token("'<'"); return LESS;}
"<="        {token("'<='"); return '<=';}
">="        {token("'>='"); return '>=';}
">"         {token("'>'"); return GREATER;}
"=="        {token("'=='"); return '==';}
"!="        {token("'!='"); return '!=';}

"&&"        {token("'&&'"); return '&&';}
"||"        {token("'||'"); return '||';}
"!"         {token("'!'"); return EXCLAMATION;}

"="         {token("'='"); return ASSIGN;}

"+="        {token("'+='"); return '+=';}
"-="        {token("'-='"); return '-=';}
"*="        {token("'*='"); return '*=';}
"/="        {token("'/='"); return '/=';}

"->"            {token("'->'"); return ARROW;}
"read"          {token("'READ'"); return READ;}

[A-Z_a-z]([A-Z_a-z]|[0-9])*             {
                                        insert(yytext, yyleng, UNDEF, linenum);
                                        yylval.symptr = lookup(yytext);
                                        tokenString("id", yylval.symptr->st_name);
                                        return ID;
                                        }               

"0"|[0-9][0-9]*                         {
                                        sscanf(yytext, "%d", &yylval.intVal);
                                        tokenInteger("integer", yylval.intVal);
                                    return INTEGER;
                                        }

[0-9_]+"."[0-9_]|[0-9_][Ee][+-]?[0-9_]+ {
                                        yylval.floatVal = atof(yytext);
                                        tokenReal("real", yylval.floatVal);
                                    return REAL;
                                        }

\"([\\.]|[^\\"])*\"                     {
                                        tempStr = malloc((strlen(yytext) - 1) * sizeof(char));
                                        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(yytext) - 2; i++)
                                        {
                                                tempStr[i] = yytext[indexForStr];
                                                indexForStr++;
                                        }
                                        tempStr[strlen(yytext) - 1] = '\0';

                                        yylval.stringVal = strdup(yytext);
                                        tokenString("string", tempStr);
                                        free(tempStr);
                                        indexForStr = 1;

                                    return STRING;
                                        }

\n      {
        LIST;
        printf("%d: %s", linenum++, buf);
        buf[0] = '\0';
        }

[ \t]*  {LIST;}

.       {
        LIST;
        printf("%d:%s\n", linenum+1, buf);
        printf("bad character:'%s'\n",yytext);
        exit(-1);
        }
%%
```

---

parser file

```
%{
#include "symbols.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Trace(t, line)        printf(t, line) // Trace where the error occurs and print the line number

#ifndef STRSIZE
#define STRSIZE     40
#endif

#ifndef PARAMSIZE
#define PARAMSIZE   40
#endif

extern FILE* yyin;
extern FILE* yyout;
extern int linenum;
extern int yylex();
void yyerror(char* msg);
%}

%union{
    char* stringVal;
    double floatVal;
    int intVal;
    int boolVal;
    list_t* symptr;
}

/* tokens */
%token <symptr> ID
%token <intVal> INTEGER
%token <floatVal> REAL
%token <stringVal> STRING
%token <boolVal> TRUE FALSE
%token INT FLOAT STR BOOL
%token BREAK CHAR CONTINUE DO ELSE
%token ENUM EXTERN FOR
%token FN IF IN LET 
%token LOOP MATCH MUT PRINT PRINTLN
%token RETURN SELF STATIC STRUCT
%token USE WHERE WHILE
%token READ PUB
%token LESS GREATER ASSIGN EXCLAMATION ARROW

/* precedence for operators */
%left '||'
%left '&&'
%left EXCLAMATION
%left LESS '<=' '>=' GREATER '==' '!='
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left UMINUS

/* types */
%type <intVal> integer_exp
%type <floatVal> real_exp
%type <stringVal> string_exp
%type <boolVal> bool_exp

%start program              /* the initial entry point */

%%
program:        functions | global_declaration functions
                ;

global_declaration:     global_declaration constant_declaration
                        | global_declaration variable_declaration
                        | global_declaration array_declaration
                        | constant_declaration
                        | variable_declaration
                        | array_declaration
                        ;

local_declaration:      local_declaration constant_declaration
                        | local_declaration variable_declaration
                        | local_declaration array_declaration
                        | constant_declaration
                        | variable_declaration
                        | array_declaration
                        ;

block:          start local_declaration statements end               
                | start local_declaration end                         
                | start statements end                                
                | start end                                           
                ;

start:          '{'                                                 {
                                                                    incr_scope();
                                                                    }

end:            '}'                                                 {
                                                                    hide_scope();
                                                                    }
                ;

functions:      functions function                                      
                | function
                ;

function:       FN ID '(' ')' start local_declaration statements end{
                                                                    if ($2->st_type == UNDEF)
                                                                    {
                                                                        $2->st_type = FUNCTION_TYPE;
                                                                        $2->inf_type = UNDEF;
                                                                    } 
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        Trace("line %d: Redeclaration of identifier.\n", linenum);
                                                                    }
                                                                    }
                | FN ID '(' ')' start statements end                {
                                                                    if ($2->st_type == UNDEF)
                                                                    {
                                                                        $2->st_type = FUNCTION_TYPE;
                                                                        $2->inf_type = UNDEF;
                                                                    } 
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        Trace("line %d: Redeclaration of identifier.\n", linenum);
                                                                    }
                                                                    }
                | FN ID '(' ')' start local_declaration end         {
                                                                    if ($2->st_type == UNDEF)
                                                                    {
                                                                        $2->st_type = FUNCTION_TYPE;
                                                                        $2->inf_type = UNDEF;
                                                                    } 
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        Trace("line %d: Redeclaration of identifier.\n", linenum);
                                                                    }
                                                                    }
                | FN ID '(' ')' start end                           {
                                                                    if ($2->st_type == UNDEF)
                                                                    {
                                                                        $2->st_type = FUNCTION_TYPE;
                                                                        $2->inf_type = UNDEF;
                                                                    } 
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        Trace("line %d: Redeclaration of identifier.\n", linenum);
                                                                    }
                ;

%%
void yyerror(char* msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "line %d: %s\n", linenum, msg);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* create the hash table */
    create();

    /* open the source program file */
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf ("Usage: sc filename\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");         /* open input file */

    int flag;
    flag = yyparse();

    /* perform parsing */
    if (flag == 1)                      /* parsing */
        yyerror("Parsing error !");     /* syntax error */

    fclose(yyin);                       /* close input file */

    /* output symbol table */
    printf("\nSymbol table:\n");
    yyout = fopen("dump.out", "w");
    dump(yyout);
    fclose(yyout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger? That would confirm exactly where the code is crashing and it is possible to see what the value of `$2` (or the variable that is actually used in the real code) is

Comment: No, I didn't run this in a debugger. I will try to run the code in a debugger to find what happened. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the problem occurs during the `dump` function when the token type is `FUNCTION_TYPE`. That's clear from the debugging output (`dump` is presumably executing when the segfault occurs) and from the change report (the problem occurs when an action sets the `st_type` field to `FUNCTION_TYPE`).

Visual inspection of the `if` clause in `dump()` corresponding to that condition reveals the following obvious error:

```
fprintf(of,"%-7s %s","function returns ");
```

That call to `fprintf` has a format string with two `%s` conversions. However, there is only one argument to be inserted.

The real question you should be asking yourself is "How can I easily find stupid typos like this without spending a lot of time or resorting to outside experts?"

As a first approximation, that error is so common and easy to detect that most compilers will warn you about it. So your first step is to make sure you *always* compile with warnings enabled (`-Wall` if you are using gcc or clang), and that you read the warnings.

Even without the warning, it would have been straight-forward to find the error with a debugger such as `gdb`. Just set a breakpoint at `dump` and single-step until the segfault occurs.

Finally, you are making your life much more complicated when you first build a large complex program with a lot of components and only then start to debug it. In the long run, you will find that it is worth taking the time to test each component individually (your symbol table, for example), using some kind of test harness, and only assembling your more complex program when you are reasonably confident that the individual pieces work. That will avoid the difficulty of identifying where the error occurred (as in this case, where you were evidently distracted by your doubts about the parser generator, leading you to miss the actual problem which has nothing to do with the parser).

---

By the way, `strncpy` is a definite red flag, although in this case you seem to have been lucky (or unlucky) enough to not encounter the bug. `strncpy` is pretty well never what you want, and if it is what you want then the length parameter should be the longest string you can accommodate rather than the length of the input string. (`strncpy` is intended for use in fixed-length formats, which is why it pads the output to the specified length.)

If you use the length of the input string, then you have two problems: (1) the copy is *guaranteed* to not be NUL-terminated, leading to Undefined Behaviour; and (2) nothing stops the copy from overrunning the output buffer, in the case that the input string is too long.

Even used correctly, `strncpy` requires you to manually NUL-terminate the output, which is a nuisance. A better solution is to first check that the string is not too long (`length < SIZE`) and then use `strcpy`, which will correctly NUL-terminate. Even better is to make the name field a char* instead of an array, and dynamically allocate a string of the correct length (see `strdup`, for example), thereby avoiding having to arbitrarily limit the size of identifiers.